# how to implement Detached XML Signatures with XML Security component in apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, ws-security, jbossfuse, xmlsec

H I have doubts with the implementation of Detached XML Signatures, I have mostly followed the example that appears [here](http://camel.apache.org/xml-security-component.html). My doubt is related to the validation that is done with the schema "test.xsd", I have not managed to generate it according to my needs.

I have to sign the body, Timestamp and BinarySecurityToken of the request, which is encrypted (for the encryption I am using the implementation that appears in http://camel.apache.org/xmlsecurity-dataformat.html)

My route camel is:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd                            http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">
<camel:keyStoreParameters id="injks" password="desarrollo" resource="C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/nuevo/test.jks"/>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.util.jsse.KeyStoreParameters" id="keyStore2">
    <property name="resource" value="C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/nuevo/test.jks"/>
    <property name="password" value="development"/>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.DefaultKeyAccessor" id="keyAccessorOne">
    <property name="alias" value="test"/>
    <property name="password" value="development"/>
    <property name="keyStoreParameters" ref="keyStore2"/>
</bean>
<!-- Parts -->
<bean class="java.util.ArrayList" id="xpathParts">
    <argument>
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureHelper" factory-method="getXpathFilter">
                <argument type="java.lang.String" value="//*:Body"/>
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureHelper" factory-method="getXpathFilter">
                <argument type="java.lang.String" value="//*:Timestamp"/>
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureHelper" factory-method="getXpathFilter">
                <argument type="java.lang.String" value="//*:BinarySecurityToken"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </argument>
</bean>
<camelContext id="context-redbanc" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="_route1">
        <from id="_from1" uri="timer:foo?period=20000"/>
        <setBody id="_setBody1">
            <simple>resource:classpath:etc/wsdl/schema.xml</simple>
        </setBody>
        <marshal id="_marshal2">
            <jaxb contextPath="cl.coopeuch.integracion.wsredbanc.wsdl.test"/>
        </marshal>
        <marshal id="_marshal1">
            <secureXML id="inEncryption"
                keyCipherAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"
                keyOrTrustStoreParametersId="injks"
                recipientKeyAlias="des-wls02.rbc.cl"
                secureTag="//*:Body" secureTagContents="true" xmlCipherAlgorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
        </marshal>
        <setHeader headerName="CamelXmlSignatureContentReferenceUri" id="_setHeader1">
            <constant>#Body</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to id="_to2" uri="xmlsecurity:sign://oneSign?keyAccessor=#keyAccessorOne&amp;digestAlgorithm=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23sha1&amp;xpathsToIdAttributes=#xpathParts&amp;schemaResourceUri=etc/wsdl/schema.xsd"/>
        <to id="_to3" uri="file://C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/salida?fileName=outbound_body.xml"/>
        <to id="_to4" uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

The elements to sign are:

```
    <bean class="java.util.ArrayList" id="xpathParts">
    <argument>
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureHelper" factory-method="getXpathFilter">
                <argument type="java.lang.String" value="//*:Body"/>
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureHelper" factory-method="getXpathFilter">
                <argument type="java.lang.String" value="//*:Timestamp"/>
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.apache.camel.component.xmlsecurity.api.XmlSignatureHelper" factory-method="getXpathFilter">
                <argument type="java.lang.String" value="//*:BinarySecurityToken"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </argument>
</bean>
```

and the uri used to sign is:

```
<to id="_to2" uri="xmlsecurity:sign://oneSign?keyAccessor=#keyAccessorOne&amp;digestAlgorithm=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23sha1&amp;xpathsToIdAttributes=#xpathParts&amp;schemaResourceUri=etc/wsdl/schema.xsd"/>
```

The test.xsd in my implementation is schema.xsd, which is: (I have not known how to indicate the other two parties to sign)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:tns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
    schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd" />
<element name="Envelope">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Header"/>
            <element name="Body">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element ref="ds:Signature" minOccurs="0" />
                    </sequence>
                    <attribute name="Body" type="ID" use="required" />
                    <attribute name="stringBody" type="string" />
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Any ideas or other examples that I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

..Is solved! The ws-policy framework was used with the following policies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsp:Policy
    wsu:Id="SecureConversation_MutualCertificate10SignEncrypt_IPingService_policy"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">

    <wsp:ExactlyOne xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsp1_2:All xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
                xmlns:wsaws="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy"
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"
                xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
                <wsp1_2:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp1_2:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                    <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference />
                                </wsp1_2:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                    <sp:ProtectTokens />
                </wsp1_2:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SignedParts
                xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702"
                xmlns:wss="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <sp:Body />
            </sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:EncryptedParts
            xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                <sp:Body />
            </sp:EncryptedParts>
        </wsp1_2:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```